# How to Read all items in a CosmosDB -- Prevent returning [object Object]

Tags: node.js, azure-cosmosdb

Good afternoon,

I've been getting stuck with the module Microsoft has in place for working with Cosmosdb. With my current setup I can write to my database all day long, however when I try to read to the database I am always unsuccessful. I think my confusion is a lack of understanding on how Microsoft handles collections.

I've got 3 main files associated to this component. App.js, dbAPI.js, and dbCTRL.js

**DbAPI** is the "lowest level" file. Its the api the controler uses to manipulate the database.

The **(dbCTRL.js)** controller creates functions which talk to the db based on the specific need of my request(in this case I literally want to see everything in the database, preferably as an array, so I can call specific key values from each document)

ASnd finally app.js is the heart and soul, this is the application that calls all these other files.
(theres also a config file which has containerID/DatabaseID,Authorization key, etc. That information is correct and for security purposes I will not share the contents of the file.)

Heres the app.js file:

```
const CosmosClient = require("@azure/cosmos").CosmosClient;
const DocumentDBClient = require('documentdb').DocumentClient;
const config = require("./db/config");
const dbCTRL = require("./controllers/dbCTRL");
const dbAPI = require("./models/dbAPI");

const express = require('express');
const path = require("path");
const logger = require("morgan");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();

const port = 3000;
const routes = require('./routes/');
const router = express.Router();
const cors = require('cors');
const helmet = require('helmet');
const fs = require('fs')

// Declare Routes
routes(router);

// View engine setup
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views"));
app.set("view engine", "jade");
app.use(logger("dev"));
app.use(bodyParser.json()) // Turns all post requests to json
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));
app.use(cors()); // Allows for Cross origin requests
app.use(helmet()); // Helps secure apps with Http headers

//Basic API Components
app.use('/api',router); 
app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Node is up!'))

const cosmosClient = new CosmosClient({
    endpoint: config.host,
    auth: {
      masterKey: config.authKey
    }
  });

  const dbApi = new dbAPI(cosmosClient, config.databaseId, config.containerId);
  const dbCtrl = new dbCTRL(dbApi);

  dbApi

    .init(err => {
      console.error(err);
    })

    .catch(err => {
      console.error(err);
      console.error("Shutting down because there was an error setting up the database.");
      process.exit(1);
    });


//Api for Creating a calendar event
//app.get('/api/createEvent'), (req, res) => {
app.get("/api/getEvents", (req, res, next) => dbCtrl.showItems(req, res).catch(next));
app.post("/api/createEvent", (req, res, next) => dbCtrl.addDoc(req, res).catch(next));

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Backend listening on ${port}!`))
module.exports = app;
```

This is the controller:
(Note: The add row module works just fine! Just cant get show items to work)

```
const dbAPI = require("../models/dbAPI");
const config = require("../db/config");

class dbCTRL {
  /**
   * Handles the various APIs for displaying and managing database items
   * @param {dbAPI} dbAPI
  */
 constructor(dbAPI) {
 this.dbAPI = dbAPI;
 }


async showItems(req, res){
  const queryspec =  'SELECT * FROM c'   
  console.log('penguins!')

const items = await this.dbAPI.find(queryspec);
  console.log('flamingos')
  console.log(Object.keys(carl))


  };


//Add new row to DB
 async addDoc(req, res) {
   const item = req.body;
   item.name = req.body.UserInput.name
   item.category = req.body.UserInput.category
   item.completed = req.body.UserInput.completed
   console.log('call made to db')
   await this.dbAPI.addItem(item);
   res.redirect("/");
 }
}

module.exports = dbCTRL;
```

And finally here is the underlying API. And after debugging where the code seems to be getting hung up:

```
/*
-- Database Api --
Have your api leverage this if you need to work with
a specific table in azure 

*/

const CosmosClient = require("@azure/cosmos").CosmosClient;
const debug = require("debug")("dbAPI");
class dbAPI {
  /**
   * Manages reading, adding, and updating Tasks in Cosmos DB
   * @param {CosmosClient} cosmosClient
   * @param {string} databaseId
   * @param {string} containerId
   */
  constructor(cosmosClient, databaseId, containerId) {
    this.client = cosmosClient;
    this.databaseId = databaseId;
    this.collectionId = containerId;
    this.database = null;
    this.container = null;
  }

  async init() {
    debug("Setting up the database...");
    const dbResponse = await this.client.databases.createIfNotExists({
      id: this.databaseId
    });
    this.database = dbResponse.database;
    debug("Setting up the database...done!");
    debug("Setting up the container...");
    const coResponse = await this.database.containers.createIfNotExists({
      id: this.collectionId
    });
    this.container = coResponse.container;
    debug("Setting up the container...done!");
  }

  async find(querySpec) {
    debug("Querying for items from the database");
    if (!this.container) {
      throw new Error("Collection is not initialized.");
    }
    const { result: results } = await this.container.items.query(querySpec).toArray();
    console.log(results)
    return results;

 }

 async addItem(item) {
   debug("Adding an item to the database");
   const { body: doc } = await this.container.items.create(item);
   return doc;
 }

 async updateItem(itemId) {
   debug("Update an item in the database");
   const doc = await this.getItem(itemId);
   doc.completed = true;
   const { body: replaced } = await this.container.item(itemId).replace(doc);
   return replaced;
 }

 async getItem(itemId) {
   debug("Getting an item from the database");
   const { body } = await this.container.item(itemId).read();
   return body;
 }
}

module.exports = dbAPI;
```

it particularly gets stuck on this line:

```
const { result: results } = await this.container.items.query(querySpec).toArray();
```

I believe my ignorance towards promise handling is whats killing me here...

I've noticed that it always outputs "**[object Object]**" I've been scratching my head at this for the past 2 days and am new to both node and Cosmosdb so if I've done something dumb some where please let me know Its very possible. Im just mind blown that I can write to a database and that took me like an hour to setup but reading the database is like impossible for me lol.

Comment: It may also be beneficial that I was trying to use this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-nodejs-application

Comment: End Goal: I have a react version of the JS module FullCalendar, I want to be able to add, delete, update, and view calendar events in a cosmosDB, and have my calendar update in real time. I've got the calendar in place, and i was reading from a json file previously, but I need this Databnase API working to get the next piece done